# IntelliJ: Adding resources to the class path, but still gives me "java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle.... locale en_US"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath, resourcebundle

I am quite new to intellij and i have loaded in a project that i wish to compile, everything seems to be going well, but when i compile it. I get the bundle cannot be found.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name openfire_i18n, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
```

After doing some investigation, it appears i have to include the resources in the class path, is this correct?

I have done Project Settings, Modules, Dependencies, and i added a "Jars or directories"

There is a checkbox that says Export, i have tried clicking it and unclicking it :-)

My resources i can see are in

> i8n\ResourceBundle

I tried adding the i8n and it asked me for a category for selected files, i put classes

RUN - but still same error..

so i tried adding the i8n/ResourceBundle directory

RUN - still same error.

I notice under my ResourceBundle directory there are

C:\Dev\Java\openfire_src_3_7_1\openfire_src\src\i18n\openfire_i18n_en.properties

but there is no specific en_US but i thought it supposed to fallback to EN ??

SO i think everything is ok.

Can anyone help

I am really stuck

Thanks

**EDIT**

I also notice that under propeties and COMPILER i have the following, so should it just include these files?

```
?*.properties;?*.xml;?*.gif;?*.png;?*.jpeg;?*.jpg;?*.html;?*.dtd;?*.tld;?*.ftl
```

**MORE INFO**

I have just added this file where all the others are but same error

```
C:\Dev\Java\openfire_src_3_7_1\openfire_src\src\i18n\openfire_i18n_en_US.properties
```

**DEBUG**

Below is the line     "ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceBaseName, locale);" and this is where it errors.

locale = en_US

and

resourceBaseName = openfire_i18n

```
Locale locale = JiveGlobals.getLocale();

ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceBaseName, locale);

return getLocalizedString(key, locale, null, bundle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `openfire_src\src\i18n` directory as **Sources** in the Module Sources tab settings, so that `.properties` files appear in the output root directory (and in the default package of the classpath).

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to CrazyCoder: The resource should be a Source Folder. It cannot be a Test Source Folder.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved same issue during setup openfire 3.9

you need to perform following task..

Open 'Run Configuration'
click on 'classpath' tab
then in 'Advanced' select 'Add folders'
then select 'i18n' from openfire/src/

follow same process and Add 'jar' folder from openfire/src/resources
and 'dist' folder from openfire/build/lib

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of intelliJ you can right-click and select "Mark directory as">"Resources root". Explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722657/how-to-mark-package-as-a-resource-folder).