# Getting Class not found in module 'app'

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, jetbrains-ide

I'm getting below error while unit testing-

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

Project structure is-
[image]

After some investigation in Run Configuration came to know its taking wrong module(main.java.com.example.dexter.sunshine.app) while running this unit case.
How can we change this module?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516289/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-junit-textui-resultpr)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue trying to run a groovy test suite.

Try right clicking the `java` directory under `src/androidTest/java` and choosing `mark directory as -> test sources root`

Comment: Excellent. I would add, that we should use the *mark directory as source root* command, too, for the root of the tested files. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36057080/715269.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and had to look for this for a little bit, and here is what I found.

Go to `Run -> Edit Configuration ...` to open `Run/Debug Configurations`.

From there you can either modify your current configurations (whether for JUnit, Android Tests, or Android Application), or you can add a new one as you need. I am sure you can change the class name there.