# Robolectric - Package targetSdkVersion=30 > maxSdkVersion=29

Tags: android, robolectric

**Error:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to configure :
> Package targetSdkVersion=30 > maxSdkVersion=29
>
> at
> org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getChildren(RobolectricTestRunner.java:247)
> at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getFilteredChildren(ParentRunner.java:534)
> at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:400)
> at
> androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.getDescription(AndroidJUnit4.java:149)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.configureRunner(RunnerBuilder.java:81)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:72)
> at
> org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
> at
> org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
> at
> org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
> at
> com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Package
> targetSdkVersion=30 > maxSdkVersion=29    at
> org.robolectric.plugins.DefaultSdkPicker.configuredSdks(DefaultSdkPicker.java:118)
> at
> org.robolectric.plugins.DefaultSdkPicker.selectSdks(DefaultSdkPicker.java:69)
> at
> org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getChildren(RobolectricTestRunner.java:213)
> ... 13 more

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808485/robolectric-and-android-sdk-29) with the same issue, with a different error message.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57261194/9636037) helped me to solve the issue.

Posting the same here.

Create a `robolectric.properties` file inside the `app/src/test/resources` directory with the following line:

```
sdk=29
```

This will force Robolectric to use API 29 instead of 30.

**Note:** Robolectric supports up to SDK 29 now (As on Sep 4th, 2020).

Comment: When you implement Android 12. It's the same solution for the newest error `Package targetSdkVersion=31 > maxSdkVersion=30`
Robolectric does not support the prerelease Android S. compile
  https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/6635

Comment: This solution still works in 2023, just change to sdk=31 and you can use the targetSdkVersion 34

Answer (score 33):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Creating prop file (mentioned in Abhimanyu's answer)

   - Create `robolectric.properties` in `app/src/test/resources`
   - Add `sdk=29` in it
2. Limit your test target SDK using `Config` annotation. This makes you consider different configs for different tests or avoid creating extra config files.

```kotlin
@Config(sdk = [29])
class Test {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Using config annotation solved my issue while creating prop file didn't.

Answer (score 11):

Both the above answers work fine, but the latest version of robolectric supports android sdk 30.

So just upgrade the robolectric dependency to fix the issue.

At the time of writing, the latest version was 4.5.1.

For the up to date version please refer the official [github](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) site.

Answer (score 2):

Just update your robolectric version to 4.5 or newer, their repo notified this change:

> Robolectric 4.5 adds support for Android API 30 (R final) and contains
> many bug fixes and other enhancements.

Source: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases

Answer (score 0):

> failed to configure com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksViewModelTest.addNewTask_setsNewTaskEvent: Package targetSdkVersion=31 > maxSdkVersion=30
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to configure com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksViewModelTest.addNewTask_setsNewTaskEvent: Package targetSdkVersion=31 > maxSdkVersion=30

Had an almost similar error as above. The error was generated when I was using AndroidX Test and Robolectic APIs to execute my local unit tests. I also had included the below code to allow The testing API use the right Android manifest file during testing:

```
 testOptions.unitTests {
    includeAndroidResources = true
}
```

I solved the above error by downgrading my compile and  target sdk from 31 to 30