# No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-espresso

I am getting the below error on running my espresso test:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
    at androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:45)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule.provideTargetContext(BaseLayerModule.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideTargetContextFactory.provideTargetContext(BaseLayerModule_ProvideTargetContextFactory.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideTargetContextFactory.get(BaseLayerModule_ProvideTargetContextFactory.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideTargetContextFactory.get(BaseLayerModule_ProvideTargetContextFactory.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideDefaultFailureHanderFactory.get(BaseLayerModule_ProvideDefaultFailureHanderFactory.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideDefaultFailureHanderFactory.get(BaseLayerModule_ProvideDefaultFailureHanderFactory.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideFailureHanderFactory.get(BaseLayerModule_ProvideFailureHanderFactory.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideFailureHanderFactory.get(BaseLayerModule_ProvideFailureHanderFactory.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_FailureHandlerHolder_Factory.get(BaseLayerModule_FailureHandlerHolder_Factory.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_FailureHandlerHolder_Factory.get(BaseLayerModule_FailureHandlerHolder_Factory.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.failureHandler(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent$ViewInteractionComponentImpl.viewInteraction(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView(Espresso.java:1)
    at com.example.espressotest.FirstTest.test1ChatId(FirstTest.java:51)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
    at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
```

`

I have added the below dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'

    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

    android {
        defaultConfig {
            testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        }
        testOptions {
            unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}
```

I tried following the solution mentioned here [AndroidX : No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595837/androidx-no-instrumentation-registered-must-run-under-a-registering-instrumen) but it didn't work for me.

Can someone help me resolve it?

Comment: Please specify what exactly you tried, as there are several approaches in the Stackoverflow thread you linked. That could help to narrow the problem.

Comment: Did you put your test classes inside the ```app/src/tests``` instead inside the ```app/src/androidTest```?
Also, check your run configuration to see if it runs under instrumentation or JUnit because running instrumented tests under JUnit shows you this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your dependencies

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
```

should be

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
```