# In the test, how to open a file in the resources directory?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm doing unit testing and for that I need to read from excel files. The files are located in the folder: `module/test/resource/click/T001.xlsx`
The test class is in the directory `module/test/java/validation/readers/spreadsheets/PlanilhaReaderTest.java` and the class I test in `src/main/java/validation/readers/spreadsheets/PlanilhaReader.java`

How do I open the directory **where it is located my files** ( ../test/resource )?

My test

```
@Test(expected = InternalServerErrorException.class)
    public void testReadMetadados_invalidPlanilha_invalidFormat() throws Exception {
        oknok.validacao.entities.Planilha planilha = new Planilha().setPath(String.valueOf(PlanilhaReader.class.getClass().getResource("/click/T001.xlsx")));
        Log.info(this, "Path: " + planilha.getPath());
        planilhaReader.readMetadados(planilha);
    }
```

Output 
Path: file:/home/daniela.morais/Development/git/myProject/myModule/**target/test-classes/**click/T001.xlsx

Comment: Are you working with Eclipse - use the context menu to make the module/test/resource folder a part of the build path (..as source folder). Then everything inside this folder will automatically copied to target/test-classes and should be found.

Comment: I working with intelliJ

Comment: Don't have IntelliJ installed here. Can you check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722657/how-to-mark-package-as-a-resource-folder - in the green section of the screenshot under "Test Source Folders also your /module/test/resource has to be.

Comment: This solved my problem, just takes the directory path:        `oknok.validacao.entities.Planilha planilha = new Planilha().setPath(PlanilhaReader.class.getClass().getResource("/click/T001.xlsx").getPath());`